# How to implement DRM static key encryption for HLS using AWS Media Convert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, drm, aws-media-convert

I want to implement static key AES128 encryption using DRM feature of AWS MediaConvert to get HLS output. I followed the following tutorial https://foliovision.com/player/securing-your-video/mediaconvert-encrypted-hls-guide Now in step 16 of this link they are recommending to use the foliovision for playing of the video. As foliovision is paid application and I want to check it for testing purpose I followed the following thread on AWS forum to create my own static key https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=828253 . But still I am not able to play my video on JWPlayer as well as I locally run VideoJS for playing HLS videos. I have enabled CORS on s3 bucket as well as on my localhost of VideoJS player so that it allows access to every website.
Can anyone let me know where am I lacking?

Comment: Can you provide any indication on what errors you are seeing, or example streams or something like that?

Comment: Generally, when I inspect the page while running it is showing no error and everything is successfully fetched(even the key stored in s3 bucket). But it is not playing the video simply

Comment: Can you see if the player is actually fetching the key? Is the key hosted on S3, or just the HLS segments?

Comment: Yes player is able to fetch the key which I have stored on s3 bucket and made public too

Comment: Hey @HetulSheth were you able to find out a solution. I am also trying to use static key for DRM in mediaconvert